# After mapping and creating a component, how do I display it in two columns as equal as how many times is rendered?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I tried using: column: 2, display: grid etc etc but nothing seems working, also justify content and align items seems not working and I am not sure why.

THIS IS WHAT I WANT TO ACHIEVE:
[image]

THIS IS WHERE I MAP MY COMPONENT:

```
 <h4 style={{ color: '#c5c5c5' }}>Recent</h4>
                  <RecentTemplatesList>
                    {RecentTemplates.map((treeNode, index) => (
                      <RecentTemplateComponent
                        // backgroundColor={template.backgroundColor}
                        key={index}
                        index={index}
                        text={treeNode}
                      />
                    ))}
                  </RecentTemplatesList>

const RecentTemplatesList = styled.div`
  position: relative;
  overflow: auto;
  height: 25vh;
  padding: 20px 0;
```

THIS IS WHERE I RENDER MY COMPONENT:

```
import React from 'react';
// styled components
import styled from 'styled-components';

const RecentTemplateComponent = ({ text }) => {
  return (
    <ListRecentTemplates>
      <TitleNStatus>
        {text} <div>Icon</div>
      </TitleNStatus>
      <Context>{'context'}</Context>
      <Treenode className="treenode">{'treenode'}</Treenode>
    </ListRecentTemplates>
  );
};
// STYLES

const ListRecentTemplates = styled.div`
  padding: 10px 0px;
  flex-direction: column;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-content: space-between;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #e5f7f4; // color from template
  
`;
const TitleNStatus = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 0px;
`;
const Context = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 0px;
`;
const Treenode = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 5px 0px;
`;

export default RecentTemplateComponent
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways to achieve a column layout. For demo purposes i used plain HTML and CSS but it should work in React as well.

**With Grid:**

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1rem;
  /* Remove default styling ul */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="card">card 1</li>
  <li class="card">card 2</li>
  <li class="card">card 3</li>
  <li class="card">card 4</li>
  <li class="card">card 5</li>
  <li class="card">card 6</li>
  <li class="card">card 7</li>
  <li class="card">card 8</li>
  <li class="card">card 9</li>
</ul>
```

**With Flex:**

**instead of adding `margin` to the cards `gap` can also be used (see grid example) but it [isn't widely supported](https://caniuse.com/?search=flex-gap) (yet)*

```css
.list {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  /* Remove default styling ul */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  flex: 0 1 calc(50% - 3rem); /* need to substract the padding and margin */
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
}

.card:nth-child(2n+1) {
  margin-right: 1rem; /* add margin-right to every 2nd item */
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="card">card 1</li>
  <li class="card">card 2</li>
  <li class="card">card 3</li>
  <li class="card">card 4</li>
  <li class="card">card 5</li>
  <li class="card">card 6</li>
  <li class="card">card 7</li>
  <li class="card">card 8</li>
  <li class="card">card 9</li>
</ul>
```

**With Columns:**

**order goes vertical instead of horizontal*

```css
.list {
  columns: 2;
  /* Remove default styling ul */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  break-inside: avoid;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="card">card 1</li>
  <li class="card">card 2</li>
  <li class="card">card 3</li>
  <li class="card">card 4</li>
  <li class="card">card 5</li>
  <li class="card">card 6</li>
  <li class="card">card 7</li>
  <li class="card">card 8</li>
  <li class="card">card 9</li>
</ul>
```

**With Float:**

```css
.list {
  /* Remove default styling ul */
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  list-style-type: none;
}

.card {
  background: teal;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
  width: calc(50% - 2.5rem); /* need to substract the padding and margin */
  margin: 0 0 1rem;
  float: left;
}

.card:nth-child(2n+2) {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="card">card 1</li>
  <li class="card">card 2</li>
  <li class="card">card 3</li>
  <li class="card">card 4</li>
  <li class="card">card 5</li>
  <li class="card">card 6</li>
  <li class="card">card 7</li>
  <li class="card">card 8</li>
  <li class="card">card 9</li>
</ul>
```